# What's the most portable way to easily allow users to add a letterhead to a Word document?

Tags: microsoft-word, macros, templates

I would like a way to allow users to easily add a letterhead (some text and a logo) to pre-existing Microsoft Word documents. Methods I have considered have been macros, templates, and quick-parts, although I am looking into other solutions. We have a central SharePoint site so ideally the solution would be easily accessible and share-able through a SharePoint document library - that is, easy to bundle up and easy for a user to install. This would most likely be for Microsoft Word 2010. Any help would be appreciated - I'm not exactly a Microsoft Word power user!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created letterhead format using a table as it's the easiest way to maintain the format.  To do that, I suggest creating a two-columned, single-row table and insert the logo into the left column using the "In Line with Text" option and right alignment for the table cell.  Insert your address/phone info into the column on the right and use left alignment for the table cell. Insert into the header of the document and make sure you select "Different First Page" in the event the letter is multiple pages.  Otherwise the letterhead will carry over to the second page.

Once you're satisfied with the formatting for the letterhead, I'd recommend creating a letterhead template (.dotx) and post it on SharePoint. You could also show people how to save the letterhead table to Quick Parts, but if you go that route you'll run into trouble when the letter has multiple pages.